# After upgrade to 2016 can't import Azure V12 bacpac

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, bacpac

We've recently upgraded our development server from 2014 to 2016. We had already been using some 2016/Azure V12 functionalities on production in certain views.

Now that we want to restore a recently exported bacpac file from our production database on Azure, it fails with the following message:

[image]

Perhaps the internal DB engine is still running on 2014? I couldn't find anything concrete about it on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation on `STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) indicates the feature is available in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2017, but not SQL Server 2016. You need to use only common features if you want to import BACPACs between different versions.

If this was working before the on-prem upgrade, I suspect that was before the proc with `STRING_AGG()` was created or changed.

Comment: Thanks, indeed. I must've misread, I assumed that `STRING_AGG` is also available on 2016.

Comment: @Feanaro - you can always try a SQL 2017 preview release if you just need an on-prem server for development purposes. It's actually very stable and should have this kind of feature that missed the SQL 2016 release window. You can even install in a container if you're worried about it impacting your local environment.